# Why is a member in a primary class template not declared in the scope of the specialized class?

Tags: c++

Please be aware that you will see an oversimplified version of the code here. So it might look useless. However, that is not the problem.

The problem is that I have a primary template class like this:

```
// The primary template class
template<int N>
struct Start {
  int start;

  template<typename... Args>
  int operator()(Args... args) const {return start;}
};
```

When I specialize this class template:

```
// Specialization for N=1:
template<>
struct Start<1> {
  int operator()(int i) const {return start;}
};
```

I get the following error:

```
error: ‘start’ was not declared in this scope
int operator()(int i) const {return start;}
```

Why is `start` not declared in the scope of class `Start<1>`?

## Question

- Why does the specialized class not recognize the member of the primary class?

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: fwiw presenting a oversimplified code is not a "problem" at all. This is a good question **because** you posted a simple and complete code that reproduces the problem in your actual code. Thanks for posting a [mcve] :)

Comment: @idclev463035818 You would be surprised how often people complain.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Template specialization is not the same as inheritance.

Your specialization is a completely different type from the primary template. No data members or functions are shared.

If you want to share a common member, then make both types inherit from a common base class.